# Is there any BroadCast Activity/services for sending an SMS?

Tags: android

i want to goes through some condition statement when a user hit a "send sms" button and thus if condition is satisfied then send the sms otherwise abort the composed sms !
 can any one help me ?

Comment: @AliImran i think you have't understand my problem, the link you given is fake for this problems.any how it was good try !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is not broad cast activity to use it when sms is going to send,

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. Any application can use `SmsManager` to send an SMS, and such messages cannot be intercepted, except perhaps by custom firmware.

You can't block an outgoing sms. You can find out about it only after it has been sent. And you can do it by registering a content observer for sms, when the sms comes to sent box.

Comment: yeah i was also thinking the same, so if will check a condition for my new sms before it delivered to some one, then i think i have to developed my own sms apps where my user will send their sms from that plat form, am i right ?

Comment: You can't intercept sent messages unless your app is sending it.

Answer (score 1):

It is good question, when you are working by using any builten application in android, then it gives you some facility upto some extent, but you can't cross the limit.
If You want to control the send button of builten apps then it is impossible. You can't do this in android.